# Return one record with multiple entries on the same date

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like

```
|   OPDNo    |DispensedDate | Drugname  | CreatedBy|
| 011650/16  | 6/29/2016    |folic acid | admin    |
| 011650/16  | 6/29/2016    |multivite  | admin    |
| 011650/16  | 6/21/2016    |fersolate  | asah     |
| 011650/16  | 6/21/2016    |amoxicyllin| eantwi   |
| 025343/13  | 5/23/2016    |aspirin    | emelia   |
```

And i want the record selection to be like this when i query like

```
select * from dispensary where OPNo='011650/16'

|   OPDNo    |DispensedDate | DrugName | CreatedBy|
| 011650/16  | 6/29/2016    |folic acid| admin    |
| 011650/16  | 6/21/2016    |fersolate | asah     |
```

That is I want only one record for every OPNo on a particular date. If an OPDNo has one or more entries on the same date, then the query should return only entry. Probably the first entry for each date if an OPDNo has more entries on that particular date.

Comment: `select DISTINCT DispensedDate,* from dispensary where OPNo='011650/16'`?

Comment: Store dates as dates. Then get back to us.

Comment: That's what I've done @Strawberry. The data type for the column DispensedDate is date. And all the values in that column are stored as such.

Comment: Please amend your question accordingly

Comment: Let's say a patient receives at least 2 drugs everyday with this month, I want a query that will select only one drug for a day for that patient irrespective of the number of drugs dispensed in a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...

```
select * from dispensary do
where do.Drugname in (select max(Drugname) from dispensary di
                      where di.OPDNo = do.OPDNo
                      and di.DispensedDate = do.DispensedDate)
and do.OPDNo = '011650/16'
```

but keep in mind that the result will not be the first drug

Comment: It doesn't matter, so far as it returns one record.

Comment: is it possible to inner join this query with a different table which has a OPDNo column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

select * from  (select * from dispensary order by DispensedDate desc) as a where OPNo='011650/16' 
group by DispensedDate;

If your DispensedDate is of type "DateTime" then you can try below

select * from  (select * from dispensary order by DispensedDate desc) as a where OPNo='011650/16' 
group by date_format(DispensedDate, '%m/%d/%Y');

Let me know if this is working.

Comment: There is an error, "The Order By clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified. "

Comment: You can place this order by inside the view otherwise.